# Java inheritence and this keyword in method called from base class but not overwritten in derived class

Tags: java

I am confused with where `this` keyword refers to in Java when using inheritance:

```
class Base{
  public String name = "base name";
  public void shout(){
      System.out.println("base class");
  }
  public void magic(){
       System.out.println(this.name);
  }
}

class Derived extends Base{
  public String name = "derived name";
  @Override
  public void shout(){
      System.out.println("derived class");
  }
}
```

nothing special here

```
    Base b = new Base()
    b.name // base name
    b.shout() // base class

Derived d = new Derived()
d.name // derived name
d.shout() // derived class
```

now,

```
Base b1 = new Derived();
b1.name; // base name <--- this is deduced from Variable type not where it refers to
b1.shout(); // derived class <--- using virtual table, method of derived class is called
```

however

```
Base b2; = new Derived();
b2.magic(); // base name
```

why does b2.magic() returns "base name"?? I thought that `this` refers to class that called the method ( and since `magic()` method isnt overwritted virtual table containts magic() method from `Base` class thus this refers to Base class ) but if i use `this` in that method like this:

```
interface Test{
    void shout();
}


static class MagicTest{
    Test test;

    public MagicTest(Test test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

    public void call(){
        test.shout();
    }
}

static class Base implements Test{
    public String name = "base name";

    public void shout(){
        System.out.println("base class");
    }
    MagicTest  magic(){
       return new MagicTest(this);
    }

}

static class Derived extends Base{
    public String name = "derived name";
    @Override
    public void shout(){
        System.out.println("derived class");
    }
}
```

And use it

```
Base b = new Derived();
b.magic().call();
```

it prints "derived class" which mean this in my example is deduced as Derived Class and now i am confused...

So my question is what does `this` refers to in method that is inherited from Base class but not overwritten in derived class?

Thanks for help.

Comment: 'this' refers to the current instance. plain and simple.

Comment: so why does call to magic() in first example prints "base name" and not "derived name"?

Comment: ok, but in the second example i declared instance of Base, and called b.magic() but this is deduced to be derived class

Comment: Are you sure a call to `magic()` returns "base name"? I cannot see how this can happen.

Comment: @Johnyb maybe show your actual code. this: Base b2; = new Derived();
b2.magic(); // base name will never compile, let alone run

Comment: oh i am sorry, magic() method should be defined in Base class, my bad ...

Comment: If `magic()` is defined in the Base class, then `this.name` will always go against the Base.name. There is no dynamic dispatch on fields, only on methods.

Comment: @Thilo ok i get it BUT then why does `this` keyword reffers to Derived Class in second example?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void magic(){
     System.out.println(this.name);
}
```

This will always go against the `name` field visible to the method body, even if `this` is a subclass instance.

There is no dynamic dispatch on fields, only on methods.

If the subclass instance also has a field called `name`, this is only confusing, but does not "override" the inherited field. The two fields are unrelated. Avoid this kind of shadowing.

> I thought that `this` refers to class that called the method

No, it does not.

`this` refers to the instance that the method is being called *on*. This will always be an instance of the class that defines the method or a subclass thereof. It has nothing to do with the caller of the method.

So if you call `a.foo()`, then `this` inside of `foo` will be `a`.

Comment: Thilo ok i get it BUT then why does this keyword reffers to Derived Class in second example -- does that mean that `this` actually reffers to refference ( derived class in second example ) but since method from superType is called it sees fields only in superType thus it always reffers to varaibles defined in superType ) ?

Comment: So if you call a.foo(), then this inside of foo will be a.  --> why is then this deduced to by derived class in second example?

Comment: You called `b.magic()` and `b` was created as `new Derived()`. So `b` is an instance of `Derived`. And `this` inside of `magic` will be `b`. In effect, you get `return new MagicTest(b);` So your `Test test` in there will also be `b`, and you end up calling `test.shout()` resolving to `b.shout()`.

Comment: @Tilo allright i think i get it. And in first example b.magic() returns base name cuz magic() is defined in Base class and base class part of my sub class does not see name defined in suptype but only on supertype...or am i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Every thing is working as it should, i don't understand your problem.

```
Base b = new Derived();
```

Calling any method on `b` object will call method form `Derived` class, if `Derived` overrides it, otherwise method from `Base` class will be called. Simple as that.

Making reference to filed on `b` object will return value of field that `Base` class contains.

For future, it's not a good idea to put same fields with same names on both base and sub class, you can use field from base class in your sub class unless it has `private` modifier. Try that and update `name` field value in `Derived` constructor. Then print it.